# Android gridview wont fill screen - only small with scroll

Tags: android

My problem is the gridView is only about 1 row high with a scroll bar and I cannot get it to fill the screen. You have to scroll down to see the other rows. I don't understand what variable makes it fill the screen or the space it has available -  I have tried changing the obvious ones.

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this);
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `layout_weight` attribute for the `GridView`? This attribute makes the View take up as much space as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `layout_with` and `layout_height` to `fill_parent`in your XML layout

or

You have to set programmatically the layout params of your GridView based on its parent type like `RelativeLayoutLayoutParams`, `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`...

```
gridView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); // for example with RelativeLayout
```

Comment: I have tried all the the above - its just not affecting it :(